# How to encode PCM file to MP3 or AC3 using Gstream pipeline in c

Tags: gstreamer

I have recorded a audio file using alsa in PCM file format and try to encode this in WAv file format using Gstream pipeline in linux terminal but I am getting a warning message like WARNING:

`erroneous pipeline: no element "audioconvert"`

The command I used is

```
--gst-launch filesrc location=file.pcm ! audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=4321, width=16, depth=16, signed=true ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=1234, width=16, depth=16, signed=true ! wavenc ! filesink location=file.wav
```

Comment: What version of GStreamer is this?

Comment: the version is GStreamer1.0

Comment: You should try `gst-inspect-1.0` and `gst-inspect-1.0 audioconvert`. If the plugin is missing you should run install `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base`

Comment: Even after installing i am getting the same issue.whether the command i used is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting the error message the audioconvert plugin is not installed correctly.  To verify the pipeline is correct, I have simulated your task below successfully using the following piplines.  Consider changing the title to something that represents the error message rather than than the particular encoding task as the pipline is fine.

## Duplicate your raw audio file

```
gst-launch audiotestsrc num-buffers=100 \
! audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=1234, width=16, depth=16, signed=true \
! audioconvert \
! audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=4321, width=16, depth=16, signed=true \
! filesink location=foo.pcm
```

## ..encode it as a WAV

```
gst-launch filesrc location=foo.pcm \
! audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=4321, width=16, depth=16, signed=true \
! audioconvert \
! audio/x-raw-int, rate=8000, channels=1, endianness=1234, width=16, depth=16, signed=true \
! wavenc \
! filesink location=foo.wav
```